# JxBrowser BrowserView component scaled incorrectly within IntelliJ Plugin on HiDPI

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, jxbrowser

I'm working on a plugin for IntelliJ and using JxBrowser to display some web content for an alternative file editor. However, the component for JxBrowswer isn't rendering in the right location or at the right size on HiDPI screens on Windows 10. (I haven't tested on other platforms yet.)

For example, on a 4K screen at 250% scaling, the browser renders up and to the left of the correct position at exactly 40% of the correct coordinate values, and with a width and height only 40% of the correct size.
[Image of improperly positioned and scaled component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuWxx.png)

Other components - such as a standard JButton - show up at the correct location and with the correct size if I replace the BrowserView component with them, so this problem appears to be specific to JxBrowser.

The browser works fine on displays that are not using scaling. This problem is present even on the latest versions of JxBrowser (6.21).

Comment: Please try running some JxBrowser sample on Java 9 or later where HiDPI support is enabled by default. If it fails the same way, submit a bug for JxBrowser. If it works on Java 9, but fails in IntelliJ IDEA running on JetBrains Runtime (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879), then file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: TL:DR; Based on your suggestion, I went back and tried a bunch of different versions of the JDK and IntelliJ. The problem if fixed by carefully lining up the JDK / IntelliJ SDK / JRE versions. Thank you for the help!
  
Longer version (for others with the same problem):  
To solve this problem, I needed to **1)** Install the latest IntelliJ  
**2)** Completely remove the IntelliJ SDKs from my projects 
**3)** Re-add the SDKs **and make sure they are set to 1.8 / 8 API level**.

The API level appears to be the critical breakdown here - any mismatch can cause this issue.